# Why UniqueId missing in the REST api result from on-premise version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest, spfile

All, I found there is a property named `UniqueId` exist in the type of [`SP.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile_members(v=office.15).aspx). And I try to retrieve the `File` item of the `Page` from `SharePoint 2013 on-premise`. The `REST` api url I used is `/_api/web/lists?&$select=Items,Items/File&$expand=Items,Items/File`.

[image]

I had thought `UniqueId` property is under the `File`node. Because I can get this property from `SharePoint 2013 online trial` , but I didn't know why it is missing from my `SharePoint 2013 on-premise`.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but there's a lack on good documentation about the differences between on premise and online versions of SharePoint, and I ended up here on my quest for information.

You need to get the UniqueId from the properties of the Item, not the File node, so add Items/UniqueId. Try changing your REST call to:

```
/_api/web/lists?&$select=Items,Items/File,Items/UniqueId&$expand=Items,Items/File
```

This should come back as:

```
          <m:properties>
            <d:UniqueId m:type="Edm.Guid">*GUID HERE*</d:UniqueId>
          </m:properties>
```

This is different to SharePoint Online, where it is not only returned here but also in the File node. This also applies to the CSOM properties.

Answer (score 0):

File resource properties do not contain UniqueId property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileProperties

Comment: Why I can get it from my `SharePoint 2013 online`? thanks.

Comment: Is the issue of `MSDN` or `SharePoint` ?

Comment: I have no access to Sharepoint 2013 online, so I can't test REST API. But "online" and "on-permise" versions are not identical and I think it can be mistake in MSDN.

Comment: I think it is a problem . because the document says `Applies to: apps for SharePoint | SharePoint Foundation 2013 | SharePoint Online | SharePoint Server 2013`. and I am sure that I can get it from `SharePoint Online`.

Comment: The document is very confused. I saw the property `GUID` of `ListItem` from REST response. But didn't see it in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552(v=office.15).aspx#ListItems